# LTRIM and RTRIM function removing extra characters than expected

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

my string is `morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clear the morning is here`.

I'm doing an `rtrim` and `ltrim` function on the string `morning is here`:

```sql
ltrim('morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clear the morning is here', 'morning is here')
rtrim('morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clear the morning is here', 'morning is here')
```

my output is:

```
ltrim -- unshine is here the sky is clear the morning is here 
rtrim -- morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clea
```

I don't get why the extra character is trimmed off?

Comment: can you please provide what you tried and expected result

Comment: Are you looking for this change ..select trim(leading 'morning is here' from 'morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clear the morning is here') -  other options are leading,trailing and both

Comment: It seems to be working as documented. What result are you expecting? What do you mean by "why the extra character is trimmed off"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you think the RTRIM function takes a *whole string* from the end and removes it. However, that is not how the function works.

From [RTRIM function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_RTRIM.html):

> The RTRIM function trims a specified set of characters from the end of a string.

If *any* of the supplied characters are at the end of the string, then it is removed. This continues until the last character is *not* any of the providing characters.

For example:

```
rtrim('morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clear the morning is here', 'eghirs ')
```

would remove any of the provided characters from the end of the string, giving:

```
morning is here sunshine is here the sky is clear the mornin
```

It looks at the *characters*, not the *string* as a whole.

In your RTRIM example, it also removed the space and `r` because those characters were included in your second argument.

If you are wondering why the command behaves this way, it is intended to be used to 'trim' unwanted characters such as spaces, tabs, quotes and punctuation. It is not intended to be used for removal of complete strings.

If you want to remove a *specific* string from the end you could use something like:

```
case when substring(column, len(column)-15, 15) = 'morning is here'
     then substring(column, len(column)-15
     else column
     end
```